# SQL server dateadd

Tags: sql-server

En **sql server** tengo que crear una nueva columna en una tabla preexistente donde me sume otra columna que tengo con segundos a la nueva a partir de una fecha:

```
alter table Emails add Date smalldatetime ALTER TABLE Emails ALTER COLUMN Date DATEADD('SECOND',Time,'11-05-2015 14:00:00')
```

Pero el error me sale en:

> SECOND, incorrect syntax expecting ID, NUMERIC, etc

Me pueden ayudar!!! Hace horas que estoy con esto

Comment: Intenta quitar las comillas a `SECOND`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores en tu código:

- El parámetro 2 del Dateadd espera un valor numérico si estás agregando segundos
- El valor en base al que quieres realizar el cálculo no lleva comillas (second)
- El alter de la columna no lleva tipo de datos, ya que es una columna calculada; adicionalmente debe ir acompañada de la cláusula "As" antes de la definición de la fórmula.

  alter table EMails add NuevaColumna  AS DATEADD(SECOND, 14, FechaParametro)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el tema es que el valor de los segundos está en la columna Time. O sea esa columna tiene datos tipo 4000, que son segundos, y se los debo sumar a '11-05-2015 14:00:00' para que me de la fecha.

Comment: Ya funcionó, muchas gracias Elena López!
ALTER TABLE Emails add Date as DATEADD(SECOND,Time,'11-05-2015 14:00:00')
Evidentemente el problema estaba en AS

Comment: @FlorenciaDiaz si te sirvió considera dar un voto positivo y marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo